# Problems with React-Bootstrap button

Tags: button, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, buttongroup

This is what i'm trying to do https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups but when I click on one of the buttons I want another function to be called

```
<ButtonGroup>
    <Button onClick = {this.onSubmit.bind(this,1)} key={1} active = {this.state.i == 1}>LEFT</Button>
    <Button onClick = {this.onSubmit.bind(this,2)} key={2} active = {this.state.i == 2}>MIDDLE</Button>
    <Button onClick = {this.onSubmit.bind(this,3)} key={3} active = {this.state.i == 3}>RIGHT</Button>
</ButtonGroup>


  onSubmit(new_i: number) {
    this.setState({
       i: new_i  
    });
  }
```

I want only one button to be active at a time, the one I click on.
The default value of i is 1. So when I start the program the LEFT button is active and the 2 others are not, which is what I want. But after I cannot click on the other buttons because the value is always 1. And finally my question is how can I change the value on I only the I click on a button.

Comment: your example seems works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46535/. However better change your example like so - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46534/

Comment: Thanks for the answer I did it as you said. In jsfiddle it is working but in my code is not working. I think I'm missing something so the only difference is that instead of  `var Buttons = window.....` I have `import Button from 'real-bootstrap` And also I don't have the `<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"/>` because I have already installed react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest if you're trying to make a item active by changing it CSS or adding a CSS class showing it's active you do something like so, this is a basic example showing that a style is being applied to an element based on the state of i.

https://jsfiddle.net/chrshawkes/64eef3xm/

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
   return { i: 1 }
  },
  onSubmit: function (value) {
    this.setState({ i: value })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick = {this.onSubmit.bind(this,1)} key={1} style = {this.state.i == 1 ? {color: "red"} : {color: "blue"}}>LEFT</div>
        <div onClick = {this.onSubmit.bind(this,2)} key={2} style = {this.state.i == 2 ? {color: "red"} : {color: "blue"}}>MIDDLE</div>
        <div onClick = {this.onSubmit.bind(this,3)} key={3} style = {this.state.i == 3 ? {color: "red"} : {color: "blue"}}>RIGHT</div>
      </div>
      )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```